# Discord.JS bot, TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: discord, discord.js

client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Node.js v18.13.0

```
const commands = [];
client.commands = new Collection();
client.commands.set("help", require("./commands/help"));
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, "commands");
const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync(commandsPath)
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
  const command = require(filePath);

  client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
  commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}
```

I have tried google, but i didnt found answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means (at least) one of your commands isn't exporting any data, which you try to access with `command.data`.

Here's an example command as shown in the [guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/slash-commands.html#individual-command-files)

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    },
};
```

If you have this in all your commands, the issue might be is that there's a non-command js file in your folders. Make sure to check that too.